# Dividing array elements on digits - problem with crashing

Tags: arrays, sorting, crash

I'm a beginner who has unfortunately encountered a problem I cannot solve :) I apologize in advance since English is not my first language.

My task is to sort an array so that the elements with the same digits come first, followed by the rest of an array.

Example:
Input array: 1 22 43 444 51 16 7 8888 90 11 -1
After sorting: 1,22,444,7,8888,11,43,51,16,90

Input array: 12, 33, 1, 19, 44, 11, 27, 76, 13
After sorting: 33, 1, 44, 11, 12, 19, 27, 76, 13

The catch is, we are not allowed to use functions or more than one array to solve the problem.

Here's what I've already tried:

```
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
    {
     digit=a[j]%10;
     while (a[j]>0)
     {
         if (a[j]%10!=digit) 
          same=0;
         a[j]/=10;
     }

     digit1=a[j+1]%10;
     while (a[j+1]>0)
     {
         if (a[j+1]%10!=digit1) 
          same1=0;
         a[j+1]/=10;
     }

     if (same==0 && same1==1)
     {
         temp=a[j+1];
         a[j+1]=a[j];
         a[j]=temp;
     }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code and why the program crashes. Thank you.

Comment: First and foremost you should document your code. Because anyone helping you will want to know what each piece is supposed to do. But more importantly because it will help you understand what you're doing. What is the index `i` and what does that outer loop accomplish? What is the index `j` and what does that inner loop accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        for (int j = in.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (in[j] < in[j - 1]) {
                int temp = in[j];
                in[j] = in[j - 1];
                in[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not really coherent your definition of the problem to the samples you are providing, for instance you say :

```
Input array  : 12, 33, 1, 19, 44, 11, 27, 76, 13 
After sorting: 33, 1, 44, 11, 12, 19, 27, 76, 13
```

But according to your statements, should not **11** be the very first element?

Please let me know if I am missing something. In any case ( and as you have not mentioned the language either ) I made this  in C++ and its working ( insofar as I could understand what you were aiming for ) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


bool samedigits(int x)
{
    //if ( x < 10 ) return false;
    int digit = x%10;
    while(x>0)
    {
        if(x%10 != digit) return false;
        x = x/10;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int same = 0;
    int same1 = 1;
    int temp = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int digit1 = 0;

    vector <int>a = { 1,22,43,444,51,16,7,8888,90,11, 99};

    for(int n : a) {
        cout << n << " ";
    }

     for (int i=0; i <= a.size() -1; i++)
        {

            for (int j=0; j <= a.size() - 1 ; j++)
            {
                if ( j != i) {

                    if (samedigits(a[j]) && samedigits(a[i])) {
                        if (a[j] > a[i]) {
                            int tmp = a[j];
                            a[j] = a[i];
                            a[i] = tmp;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }else if (! samedigits(a[j]) && samedigits(a[i]) ) {
                            int tmp = a[j];
                            a[j] = a[i];
                            a[i] = tmp;
                            continue;

                    } else if ( samedigits(a[j]) && ! samedigits(a[i]) ){
                        continue;
                    }else {
                        if (a[j] > a[i]) {
                            int tmp = a[j];
                            a[j] = a[i];
                            a[i] = tmp;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    for(int n : a) {
        cout << n << " ";
    }

}
```

And it returns :

[image]

I neither get if you were considering a single digit number as being an "elements with the same digits". Hence, I commented a line that can fit well with that view or not. Feel free to comment.

You can test this here :

https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++

Regards!